# Firebase - Passing on info from activity with persistence enabled

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app in which users create "posts" and all the posts are displayed in a list.

Upon clicking a post in the list, the whole post is displayed in a new activity.

To view posts even when the app is offline I have used:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Since performance of my app is a big concern for me I want to ask how should I **pass on post info from the list to the activity** which displays the full post.

1) Should I use intents & pass on all individual info like author name, timeStamp, post-body through:

```
intent.putExtra
```

OR

2) Use ValueEventListeners which **"I'm guessing when the app is offline or when the post has been downloaded get the data from the local database created by Firebase when persistence is enabled."**

```
        // Add value event listener to the post
    // [START post_value_event_listener]
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            mAuthorView.setText(post.author);
            mTitleView.setText(post.title);
            mBodyView.setText(post.body);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            Toast.makeText(PostDetailActivity.this, "Failed to load post.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    };
    mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
    // [END post_value_event_listener]
```